# The Role Manager feature has not been enabled error during controller unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, roleprovider

I'm doing unit testing for my controller's method.
In following method, I want to check if the return type is `ViewResult`

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddRepresentative(Guid businessUnitId)
    {
        var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        var model = new AddRepresentativeModel
        {
            BusinessUnitId = businessUnitId,
            Roles = roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = r,
                Text = r,
            })
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is what i've done for testing

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void AddRepresentative_Get_Action_RendersView()
    {
        var result = _controller.AddRepresentative(Guid.Empty);

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result,typeof(ViewResult));
    }
```

**Error**:

> Test method
>   AdminPortal.Tests.Controller_Test.Customer.BusinessUnitControllerTests.AddRepresentative_Get_Action_RendersView
>   threw exception:  System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The
>   Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

**Question**:
Is it not good practice to collect list of roles in HttpGet method?

Is there some change that i need to make in my controller or test method in order make the test pass?

Is the error occurring because I'm using RhinoMock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it not good practice to collect list of roles in HttpGet method?

There's nothing wrong with it.

> Is there some change that i need to make in my controller or test method in order make the test pass?

Yes, you could add an app.config file to your unit test project and register a role manager in the `<system.web>` section, the same way you did in your actual application. Otherwise where do you think the `Roles.GetAllRoles();` method will get any data from? Alternatively you could wrap this call in a service layer that could be mocked in your unit test.

> Is the error occurring because I'm using RhinoMock?

No.